# Updating a manually installed Rocket.Chat instance

Tags: updating, rocket.chat

Documentation on updating Rocket.Chat (found [here](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/updating/)) only says:

> Usually you can upgrade Rocket.Chat without much effort,
>
> There might be some major changes when we introduce big new features or modifications, you can always take a look on the releases page to see what has been changed, broken or added to Rocket.Chat.

My question: Does anyone have experience in updating/upgrading a manually installed Rocket.Chat deployment & what did you do other than redeploy latest code?

[Here](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/ubuntu/) is the procedure for a manual install on Ubuntu, we're using 16.04 LTS.

At the moment we're on 0.58.2 & I want to update to 0.62.0 (latest), however there's no indications on how to update the database, and the only way to update the code I've seen is to download it & deploy it as a new install on the same server. Will the code handle MongoDB migration to latest?

All I've found so far are dev questions and implementations not directly related to this type of installation of Rocket.Chat, and would love to craft a procedure to update in the future, if it's not so simple as just redeploying on top of an existing installation. I will update this with information as it comes in, and if I find a solution in the meantime I will also come back and update for anyone looking to google for an answer in the future.

Thanks

Comment: The forum might be a better place for this multi-question.  forums.rocket.chat - we should probably add to our issue template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking a lot of varying questions here.

Upgrading between versions of Rocket.Chat typically the only factor is the nodejs version.  In your case definitely make sure you upgrade to node.js 8.x

Database migrations are handled in the Rocket.Chat code base.

Also if MariaDB is involved in your installation.  It's not being used by Rocket.Chat(or if so please share the code ;) ) because Rocket.Chat uses MongoDB.

Comment: Edited to reflect MongoDB, had been debugging too much Maria that day! Thank you for the feedback, marking this as solved.

Comment: Updated to node 4.8.4, then 8.9.3, with 0.63.0 code gives "Unexpected token import" on startup. I've posted on community support, will update this thread with more details for posterity.

Comment: For the record versions of Rocket.Chat have a supported version of nodejs.  Using greater then that supported version.  Especially between major node versions.. is very prone to breakage.  Especially I imagine 4.x to 8.x